# Javascript return not breaking out of function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function which checks to see if an artist exists in an XML file:

```
function artistExists(artist) {
// get data from artists.xml 
$('.loading').show();
$.get(artists_xml, function(xml){  
    $('.loading').hide();
    $(xml).find('artist').each(function(){
        if ($(this).find("ar_artist").text() == artist.val()) {
            alert ('artist exists');
            return true;
        } //end if
    });  // end each
    alert ('artist does not exist');
    return false;
}); // end .get function
} // end of artistExists function
```

Am I right in thinking that the 'return true' line should quit execution of the function? I thought it would, but after finding a record and running the first alert execution continues to the failure alert at the bottom.

What am I doing wrong please? Thank you.

Answer (score 26):

Yes, it does "quit" execution of the function. The question is, "which function?"  In this case the answer should be pretty clear: it's the function passed to `.each()`.

You can terminate the looping behavior of `.each()` by returning `false` instead of `true`, but that still won't get you out of the outer function.  What you should probably consider is to set up a local variable in the outer function, and have the inner function set that when it finds something (and then break the `.each()` loop).  Then the main function can check the local variable to see if it was set.

This is a case where I'd really like to use a `.reduce()` or `.inject()` API, but jQuery doesn't have one and they're really opposed to it.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, it works, though it does seem a bit clunky doesn't it. It'd be great if could put numbers after a break statement.

Comment: Well the problem is that when your functions are first-class values like in JavaScript, the "static" arrangement of the code really doesn't tell you much about how/when/where a function will actually be called.

Answer (score 15):

Return `false`, rather than `true`, to terminate the `each` loop; from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

> We can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning `false`.

That will just terminate your `each` loop, though, not the overall function. You'll need to set a flag so you know whether you found something, e.g. something like this:

```
function artistExists(artist) {
// get data from artists.xml 
$('.loading').show();
$.get(artists_xml, function(xml){  
    var found = false;    // <== Added
    $('.loading').hide();
    $(xml).find('artist').each(function(){
        if ($(this).find("ar_artist").text() == artist.val()) {
            alert ('artist exists');
            found = true; // <== Added
            return false; // <== Modified
        } //end if
    });  // end each
    if (!found) {         // <== Added
        alert ('artist does not exist');
    }                     // <== Added
    return found;         // <== Modified
}); // end .get function
} // end of artistExists function
```

Comment: It's been a long long time, but I have a question about it: I tried to use `return` only and it stopped the `.each`, so is `return false` not a must-do or is there something I should know?

Comment: @CagatayUlubay: Just `return` won't stop the `each` loop, it just jumps out of the callback for that one iteration; the loop will continue with the next iteration. `return false` will jump out of the callback for that iteration **and** stop looping.

Answer (score 4):

`$.get` is an asynchronous function, that means, the main function, `artistExists` will return immediately, and a GET request will be initiated. To be able to get the result you will need a callback.

```
function artistExists(artist, cb) {
    $('.loading').show();
    $.get(artists_xml, function(xml) {

        var found = false;

        $('.loading').hide();

        $(xml).find('artist').each(function(){
            if ($(this).find("ar_artist").text() == artist.val()) {
                found = true;
                return false; // use return false to stop .each()
            }
        });

        // the built in action.
        if (found) {
            alert ('artist exists');
        } else {
            alert ('artist does not exist');
        }

        // call the callback function
        cb (found);

    });
}
```

Then to use, you need to use a callback function. From

```
var isExists = artistExists('lol');
// do stuff
```

You need to change it to:

```
artistExists('lol', function(isExists) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this Thai - on refection this is obviously the way to go. I just don't quite understand how to use it in my code, I'm new and I've never used a callback before. I wanted to be able to have a line of code like "if (artistExists($('#artistfield'))) { // do stuff }". How would I go about this with the callback business please? Thanks very much.

Comment: An asynchronous function means a function that you can't get the result instantly when you call. A callback function is important so that you can be notified when the result is available. If you take a look, the `artistExists` function accepts another argument `cb`, and `cb` is called after we have the result on `cb(found)`.

Comment: thanks again Thai. I understand that the asynchronous nature of the request means I have to wait for the result. What I'm not clear about is how i use my cb/callback function to pass true/false back to my original calling line of code. If you could help me with a bit of code here I'd be really grateful. thanks again.

Comment: It is higher order programming, where you pass pass a piece of code as values (in JavaScript, it is a function). Then a code can call it like any other functions, so you can call it like the way you do in `$.get('url', function(response){ ... })` or `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`. I recommend that you read a bit about functional programming: [Functional Programming -- Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html)

Comment: Thanks Thai, that'll make for some interesting and well needed reading.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the advice. In the end I decided I needed a synchronous call, so I made the following new version of the .get function, called .sget:

```
    jQuery.extend({
sget: function( url, callback, type ) {
        return jQuery.ajax({
            type:       "GET",
            url:        url,
            success:    callback,
            async:      false,
            dataType:   type
        });
    }
});
```

The 'async: false' pair in the 'ajax' options makes the call synchronous. Then the following edit of my original failing function:

```
function artistExists(artistname) {
var found = false;
console.log("From Input:Artist= " + artistname.val());
// get data from artists.xml
$('.loading').show();
$.sget(artists_xml, function(xml){  // new synchronous get
    $('.loading').hide();
    $(xml).find('artist').each(function(){
        if ($(this).find("ar_artist").text() == artistname.val()) {
            console.log('From File:Artist= ' + $(this).find("ar_artist").text());
            found = true;
            console.log("In each loop:Flag= " + found);
            return;
        } //end if
    });  // end each
}); // end .get function
console.log("At end:Flag= " + found);
return found;
```

}

The console.log lines will be removed. They show though, that things are now happening in the order I want. SO the new synchronous .sget function and the use of a 'found' flag, as advised above, have done the trick for me. Don't know why I couldn't think of doing this yesterday.

Thanks everyone.